# Stuck in LineageOS boot logo when installing on Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 global

Tags: twrp, fastboot, lineageos, xiaomi

I booted TWRP 3.2.3-0 using fastboot, then followed [#5 unlocking fastboot](https://forum.xda-developers.com/redmi-note-5-pro/how-to/index-everything-anti-roll-t3816219) to install it permanently on my Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 cause of the problematic anti-rollback from Xiaomi. Next, I installed [the LineageOS zip](https://download.lineageos.org/whyred). It shows the LineageOS boot animation but then nothing happens. Even after waiting more than 1h it doesn't boot.

Things I tried yet without success:

- 20181016, 20181003 and 20180926 LineageOS builds
- Factory reset using TWRP
- Advanced TWRP wipe with data, system, cache and dalvik cache
- Disabled the installing of TWRP app after flashing
- Deleted dalvin cache after flashing before rebooting
- Flashing using [adb sideload](https://rootmygalaxy.net/how-to-use-adb-sideload-to-install-roms-and-mods-on-android/)
- Install LineageOS together with corresponding OpenGAPS Zip
- Waiting ~20min in boot animation, force shutdown and start manually

**What worked**

- [MoKee](https://www.mokeedev.com/) booted shortly after the first try without google apps

#### Preparation for flashing

Before flashing, I used AIDA64 with the stock MUI ROM to make sure that the codename match:

[image]

So the `whyred` image is correct, which matches the information I read before buying that the global version is equal to Pro, where official LineageOS builds can be installed.