# What kind of encryption is required for LineageOS on Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 (whyred) to boot?

Tags: encryption, lineageos, xiaomi

[Having my Redmi Note 5 stuck at the LineageOS logo](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/202954/stuck-in-lineageos-boot-logo-when-installing-on-xiaomi-redmi-note-5-global), I tried different ROMs like Resurrection Remix OS. They work well. After some reserach, I found a hint to some kind of encryption in the [LineageOS release thread on xda-developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=77100560&postcount=2). So I re-flashed the stock MIUI ROM ([without firmware](https://forum.xda-developers.com/redmi-note-5-pro/how-to/index-redmi-note-5-pro-miui-roms-t3816343) cause of Xiaomi's devious anti roll-back mechanism) and LineageOS could be installed without problems.

I want to understand this topic:

- What are those keys?
- Why LineageOS needs them?
- Has this anything to do with [device encryption](https://www.howtogeek.com/141953/how-to-encrypt-your-android-phone-and-why-you-might-want-to/)?
- Is this a Xiaomi specific topic or does it apply to other manufactures as well?

Currently, I know very little about those encryption keys:

- It seems that they're generated by the stock MIUI on first boot
- They got deleted by formatting in TWRP, not on simply wiping
- We don't get any usefull error message, only a endless booting LineageOS animation
- Encryption can be bypassed using a zip from [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=77100560&postcount=2). But without [OTA updates](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/95epl4/first_time_booting_is_taking_forever_on_whyred/e4tpq1m/) and the zip for bypassing must be flashed on each LineageOS update
- Other ROMs like MoKee or Resurrection Remix OS don't care

Comment: Really interesting question, something which confusing me too. Would be nice if some experienced user or developer could bring light into the dark of this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Format data using TWRP, unmount the data partition, then resize the partition with adb shell :
resize2fs /dev/block/mmcblk0p50 51G

(my original size of filesystem /dev/block/mmcblk0p50 was 52.1G (you can find it with the command "df -h /dev/block/mmcblk0p50")
The encryption process need to take some place at the end of the partition or it will fail - this thread has helped me : github.com/CyanogenMod/android_device_motorola_xt907/issues/3
You can debug also the problem with the adb logcat command.